# redux doesn't work well with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react-router event like so

```
//src/App/components/common/Notifications
onCommentClick = (id) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/dashboard/${id}`)
}
```

It will change the browser url, my route is setup correctly I guess

```
//src/App/containers/dashboard/user/NotificationDetail
```

but the problem is redux doesn't seem to rerender my container component, I need to refresh to get the right content.

source https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux

stuck on this for 1 day couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this ->

```
@withRouter
@connect(state => state.global, {
  getNotifications
})
```

Use `mapStateToProps()` ->

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
     notifications: state.notifications
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
// your actions here
}

export const NotificationsComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)(Notifications)
```

It will rerender your component whenever your redux state updates.

Comment: connect is from react-redux, which is the same with what you've said, try your method in the repo I guarantee that you won't made it.